# Add Id attribute to soap body element in IClientMessageInspector implementation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I've a bit of code that inserts an X509 certificate into a soap header that seems to work OK.

```
private Message SignMessage(Message request)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var a = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
    a.CreateMessage().WriteMessage(writer);
    writer.Close();

    doc.LoadXml(sb.ToString());

    //This is needed or added the Reference.Uri to the signed Xml will fail
    var attr = doc.CreateAttribute("Id");
    attr.Value = "MyId";
    doc.GetElementsByTagName("s:Body")[0].Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr);

    var signed = new SignedXml(doc);

    var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "6e 3c 63 19 bf 19 4b 6d 1b b0 88 1e 57 f0 16 00", true)[0];
    signed.SigningKey = cert.PrivateKey;

    //Set Reference.Uri
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.Uri = "#MyId";

    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoX509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data(cert);
    keyInfoX509Data.AddSubjectName(cert.IssuerName.Name);
    keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoX509Data);

    signed.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

    //Add reference to signed xml
    signed.AddReference(reference);
    signed.ComputeSignature();

    XmlElement signature = signed.GetXml();

    request = a.CreateMessage(); 
    var element = doc.GetElementsByTagName("s:Header")[0];

    element.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(signature, true));

    var xSig = XElement.Parse(element.OuterXml);

    foreach (var xElement in xSig.Elements())
    {
        if (xElement.Name.LocalName == "Signature")
        {
            //Add signature to header here
            var sigDoc = new XmlDocument();
            sigDoc.Load(xElement.CreateReader());

            var list = new XmlNode[sigDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0).ChildNodes.Count];

            for (int x = 0; x < sigDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0).ChildNodes.Count; x++)
            {
                list[x] = sigDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0).ChildNodes.Item(x);
            }

            MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(xElement.Name.LocalName,
                xElement.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName, list);
            request.Headers.Add(header);
        }

    }

    return request;
}
```

The problem I'm having now is how to use that certificate to sign the soap body element. I need the soap body element to match `MyId` set in `Reference.Uri` but can't seem to make any changes to the body tag. All I seem to be able to do is make changes to the content of the body rather than adding something to the body tag itself.

So at the moment it looks like so:

```
<s:Body>
```

But I need it to look like so:

```
<s:Body Id="MyId">
```

Any way I can do that by manipulating the Message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Message.CreateMessage(XmlDictionaryReader, Int32, MessageVersion)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586762.aspx) solved the problem. Manipulate the xml and then create the new message from the xml.