# Signing a Soap Message, but can't reference the Body with a u-id attribute

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap-client, connected-services

I'm using a generated Connected Service ( Soap) to generate the signature.

The server only expects the message to be signed on the body. So I need to provide reference with an Id of the Body.

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the <s:body> xml element. Using an endpointbehavior and replacing the Message using Message.CreateMessage appends the newly created <s:body ( with an id) to the original <s:body>.

How should I do this, if it's not supported by an EndPointBehavior.

- Tried using EndpointBehavior
- Tried fine-tuning WsHttpBinding and BasicHttpBinding
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755156/add-id-attribute-to-soap-body-element-in-iclientmessageinspector-implementation)  doesn't seem to work, perhaps too little details?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [this link](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/ws/2005/02/23/salz.html) to add the id attribute in body.

Comment: @Jiayao The limitation is in a connected service in .net, not from SOAP itselve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using the original flow of a connected service anymore. I just send the request now and sign the body "manually".